# gedit is crashing again and again

Tags: crash, gedit, mate, text-editor, evernote

I am using ubuntu mate 18.04 and I installed gedit in it alongside pluma (mate default text editor) so I can manage my text notes with gedit. I was also using this setup in ubuntu 16.04, ubuntu mate 16.04 and even in ubuntu mate 18.04 and it works really great. A few days ago I reinstalled my ubuntu mate, install gedit and some necessary plugins and now gedit is crashing in almost in all sessions. I used gedit to manage all my notes and journal entries but this problem is making it impossible. I removed and install gedit multiple time, check with and without plugins but nothing is working. Can anyone help?

update: when I launch this program in the terminal, it crashes after some time with the following error.

```
(gedit:26250): Gdk-ERROR **: 01:25:37.372: The program 'gedit' received an X Window System error.
This probably reflects a bug in the program.
The error was 'BadLength (poly request too large or internal Xlib length erro'.
  (Details: serial 2911131 error_code 16 request_code 18 (core protocol) minor_code 0)
  (Note to programmers: normally, X errors are reported asynchronously;
   that is, you will receive the error a while after causing it.
   To debug your program, run it with the GDK_SYNCHRONIZE environment
   variable to change this behavior. You can then get a meaningful
   backtrace from your debugger if you break on the gdk_x_error() function.)
Trace/breakpoint trap
```

Comment: http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html We would love to help, but it is hard witout relavent information, or any information for that matter

Comment: @j-money I sorry if this is a stupid question but can I ask which relevant information I need to provide, in order to get help

Comment: can you launch it from a terminal? If so what is the terminal output when it crashes?

Comment: Are these notes stored locally? I notice `gedit` often crashes if you edit notes on a remote server (e.g. over Samba or FTP) and don't save every few minutes, i.e. you don't keep the connection alive.

Comment: @Jos I store them on dropbox.

Comment: What are the size of the files you are editing?  I recall looking at a problem ~recently with `leafpad` accessed thru network (eg. samba/cifs) which also occurred in pluma & gedit it turned out.  It was the size of the files (a limitation in network protocol but I forget the detail, and can't look up the bugs now).  Looking at logs (or crash reports if run from terminal as already suggested) should provide more clues..  Are the files huge?

Comment: Does GEdit crash if you log into another user account?

Comment: @j-money I just updated my question with the terminal error. Can you have a look, please!

Comment: @guiverc files size is around 28.0 kb. just posted crash report above, please have a look.

Comment: @heynnema I just have one user account and I manager everything from that.

Comment: The idea of trying another account is to eliminate something in your own directory causing the problem. Create a temporary account called "Guest", and try gedit there. Otherwise, rename `~/.config/gedit` to `~/.config/gedit.HOLD`, then retry gedit and see if it works. Report back.

Comment: @heynnema I renamed gedit config folder and launch it with the terminal, this time it did not crash. Another thing I notice that ~/.config/gedit folder did not belong to the current user but root.

Comment: @heynnema I am sorry but I didn't get from your answer that why I was facing this problem? and how I will solve it permanently?

Comment: Please re-read the complete answer. You probably started gedit from the terminal using `sudo gedit`... and the fix is there...

Answer (score 3):

From the comments...

We renamed `~/.config/gedit` to `~/.config/gedit.HOLD`, then retry gedit and see if it works. It worked. So something is wrong with this prefs folder. It's owned by root.

You probably started gedit in the terminal using `sudo gedit`, and you should be using `sudo -H gedit`. All GUI apps should be started this way from the terminal.

Comment: I am again facing the same issue.

Comment: @ShahMoeen How did you start gedit?

Comment: from start menu

Comment: Did you put the original gedit config folder back, or did you leave the new one in place and delete the old folder? Have you added any gedit extensions? Is ~/.config owned by root, or your username?